# Possible Glitch? BBP python algorithm

Tags: python-2.7

For some reason, both my online, and desktop compiling environments think that everything is invalid syntax all of the sudden! here is my code:

```
def sumn(n): #summation for sigma
return ((n + 1) * n) / 2
ipt = raw_input('How In Depth Would You Like To Go? ')
ipt = int(ipt)
pi = sumn(ipt) * ((4 / (8 * ipt + 1)) - (2 / (8 * ipt + 4)) - (1 / (8 * ipt + 5)) - (1 / (8 * ipt + 6)) * (1 / (16 ^ ipt))
print pi
```

Comment: Body of ``sumn()`` is not indented.

Comment: did you forgot to give indentation in `sumn(n)` and close parenthesis for `pi = `?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your indent for the function `sumn(n)`is invalid.
2. Your syntax for line : `ipt = int(raw_input('How In Depth Would You Like To Go? '))` is incorrect.
3. For power use `**` instead of `^`.

I've got your code working with proper indentation and syntax for `pi`:

```
>>> def sumn(n): #summation for sigma
        return ((n + 1) * n) / 2
>>> ipt = float(raw_input('How In Depth Would You Like To Go? '))
How In Depth Would You Like To Go? 4
>>> pi = sumn(ipt) * ((4 / (8 * ipt + 1)) - (2 / (8 * ipt + 4)) - (1 / (8 * ipt + 5)) - (1 / (8 * ipt + 6)) * (1 / (16 ** ipt)))
>>> print pi
0.386291370825
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me my error, but I think these answers are incorrect, because the answer for 4 is roughly 0.386.  Also any input larger than 16 crashes the program.

Comment: @EDP554 Program is giving correct solution now, I have converted int to float. Also I have changed `^` to `**`. It is working for values greater than 16 as well.

Comment: Thank you, but the advantage of my code is that you can calculate with further points than just 12 points, and it needs to add up the answers for 0 - 4, which mine can already do.

Answer (score 0):

Yayy, I finally solved it!

```
from decimal import * 
def sumn(n): #summation for sigma
    return ((n + 1) * n) / 2
ipt = int(raw_input('How In Depth Would You Like To Go? '))
getcontext().prec = ipt


def factorial(n):
    if n<1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
def BBP(n):
    pi = Decimal(0)
    k = 0
    while k < n:
        pi += (Decimal(1) / (16 ** k)) * ((Decimal(4) / (8 * k + 1)) - (Decimal(2) / (8 * k + 4)) - (Decimal(1) / (8 * k + 5)) - (Decimal(1) / (8 * k + 6)))
        k += 1
    return pi   
print BBP(ipt)
```

ex.

```
How In Depth Would You Like To Go? 1000
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420193
```

The last two values are usually wrong though, and I am still working on trying to truncate them.  Then all I have to do is add 2 to ipt, which would take me all of 5 seconds ☺